# Error running Android project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

i have this error when i run my application,  Unfortunately, “AppNameHere” has stopped working...

This is the error log and files.

```
    05-23 18:03:23.537: D/ AndroidRuntime (1289): Shutting down VM
    05-23 18:03:23.537: W/dalvikvm(1289): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a77ba8)
    05-23 18:03:23.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1289): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    05-23 18:03:23.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1289): Process: com.example.holausuario, PID: 1289
    05-23 18:03:23.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1289): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.holausuario/com.example.holausuario.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    05-23 18:03:23.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
    05-23 18:03:23.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
    05-23 18:03:23.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    05-23 18:03:23.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    05-23 18:03:23.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    05-23 18:03:23.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    05-23 18:03:23.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    05-23 18:03:23.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    05-23 18:03:23.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    05-23 18:03:23.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    05-23 18:03:23.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    05-23 18:03:23.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    05-23 18:03:23.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1289): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    05-23 18:03:23.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     at com.example.holausuario.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
    05-23 18:03:23.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    05-23 18:03:23.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    05-23 18:03:23.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
    05-23 18:03:23.557: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     ... 11 more
    05-23 18:06:35.097: I/Process(1289): Sending signal. PID: 1289 SIG: 9
```

manifiest:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.holausuario"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.holausuario.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

fragment_main.xml

```xml
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.holausuario.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/LblNombre"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Escribe tu nombre:" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BtnHola"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TxtNombre"
            android:layout_below="@+id/TxtNombre"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:text="Aceptar" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/TxtNombre"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/LblNombre"
            android:layout_below="@+id/LblNombre"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```java
    package com.example.holausuario;

    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.content.Intent;

    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


         // OBTENGO LA REFERENCIA DE LOS OBJETOS CREADOS EN EL FORM DEL MAIN PRINCIPAL

            final Button btnHola = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BtnHola);
            final EditText txtNombre = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TxtNombre);

          //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

            btnHola.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


                public void onClick(View v) {


                    // Creamos el Intent, el cual se comunica entre distintas aplicacion y componentes.
                    Intent intent =
                            new Intent(MainActivity.this, FrmSaludo.class);

                  //Creamos la información a pasar entre actividades en el objeto Bundle que contiene la estructura ( clave, valor ), en pocas palabras son las variables que puedes enviar de pagina a pagina
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putString("NOMBRE", txtNombre.getText().toString()); // añadimos el variable string al objeto, mediante la estrcutura ( clave, valor )

                    //Añadimos la información al intent, ya que el intent es el que te permite interactuar de pagina a pagina.
                    intent.putExtras(b);


                  //Iniciamos la nueva actividad y le pasamos el intent el cual nos muestra a la pantalla que mandamos, osea iniciamos el envio de pagina a pagina
                    startActivity(intent);
                }



            });



            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                        .commit();
            }
        }




        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        /**
         * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
         */
        public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

            public PlaceholderFragment() {
            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
                return rootView;
            }
        }

    }
```

activity_saludo.xml

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TxtSaludo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

FrmSaludo.java

```java
package com.example.holausuario;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FrmSaludo extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_saludo); // aqui decimos que esta clase manipula los objetos del activity_saludo.xml

     // OBTENGO LA REFERENCIA DE LOS OBJETOS CREADOS EN EL FORM DEL MAIN PRINCIPAL

             TextView txtSaludo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TxtSaludo);

     // ------------------------------------------------------------------------        

             //Recuperamos la información pasada en el intent
             Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();

             //Construimos el mensaje a mostrar
             txtSaludo.setText("Hola " + bundle.getString("NOMBRE"));
    }
}
```

I'm just learning to program in android

somebody help me please... thank

Comment: post your code in addition to your logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your button is in your fragment_main.xml file, but in your mainactivity,you setContentView(R.layout.activity_main), so  in your mainActivity ,you can't by findviewbyid to get a button object, button is null, so your program throw a NullpointException .

Comment: i am new in this, when i create a new aplicattion android, my eclipse create two file: activity_main.xml and fragment_main.xml, but te file that is the object is fragment_main.xml...

please, help me., what must i do ?.. thank...

Comment: setContentView(fragment_main.xml),this xml is what you want to display in your screen, the activity_main.xml is the defautl file

Comment: in my MainActivity.java change for SetContentView(R.layout.fragment_main) but a i have the same problem..

Comment: 5-26 10:45:13.283: E/FragmentManager(1162): No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.holausuario:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{b3dd0060 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
05-26 10:45:13.283: E/FragmentManager(1162): Activity state:
05-26 10:45:13.293: D/FragmentManager(1162):   Local FragmentActivity b3d84ec8 State:
05-26 10:45:13.293: D/FragmentManager(1162):     mCreated=truemResumed=false mStopped=false mReallyStopped=false